# Create json Object in json Object and return it to Ajax

Tags: c#, json

I currently have an `List<Translations>` in c# with this structure:

```
public class Translations
{
    public string en { get; set; }
    public string de { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to convert it now to an **Json Object** , because my function which calls this webservice by Ajax, needs the data exactly with the following structure:

```
{
    de: { //-> de stands for the stored value in translations class
        'en_GB': en, //-> en stand for stored  value in translations class
        'de_DE': de // -> de same value as the key de
    }, 
    de: {
        'en_GB': en,
        'de_DE': de
    },
        de: {
        'en_GB': en,
        'de_DE': de
    }, 
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?
I have already tried to create the classes I need with this tool: [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) but the problem here is that I need to have **dynamic key names** of every object in my object. With this tool It creates me a static one for every object.

**Solution** *thanks to the help from Riaz Raza*:

```
public static string getTranslations()
{
    List<Translations> translations = Connector.TranslationList();
    int count = translations.Count - 1;
    var translationsObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        translationsObject.Add(
           translations[i].de,
           new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                 { "en_GB", translations[i].en },
                 { "de_DE", translations[i].de } }
             );

    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(translationsObject);
}
```

Comment: *"exactly with the following structure"* You can't. This is invalid JSON (duplicated keys)

Comment: actually the `de:` is dynamic. every `de` has a different value. so no duplicated key. Sorry if I didnt explained this clearly

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Many JSON serialisers will convert `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to dynamically named values in JSON but, I don't understand how your desired JSON would map to your `Translations` type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of type `Dict<string, object>` instead of a class and populate it dynamically to match your required JSON object.

UPDATE:

Sample Code:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dic.Add("de", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "en_GB", "en" }, { "de_DE", "de" } });
```

Comment: Thank you at least I have the same structure as my Json Object now in C# but somehow  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic)` only works with `<string, string>` not with `<string, object>`

Comment: works now. updated my question with my final solution. thanks for your help! Very easy solution

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be, if you want to use a C# data model in JSON you have to modify your JS function that receive data so it will accept the data from C# model. This will be the more accurate way of doing it.

But if you can't access the JS code or it is restricted from modification, you can use **Newtonsoft** [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateWithJsonNetAttributes.htm) attributes this will allow you to make a modifications to your JSON document when building it from DataModel.

Here is some example from Newtonsoft:

```
public class User
{
    // always require a string value
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // don't require any value
    [JsonProperty("role", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    // property is ignored
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

If this would't solve your problem it is always hardcode way of doing things with build the JSON string manually with Regex and etc. But I would recommend this as last option, in most cases it is possible to deal with JSON without hardcode.

Referring to your comment that every `de:` is uniq, it is would be better to form your JSON documment as array.

This will allow you to deserialize it as array and iterate through it.

Comment: @LukasR. It is actually not good tactic to form data on the client it will make your web page slow if you will do the parsing and other stuff on the client.

So my advice you should form your data in appropriate format on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to modify your existing data models, I believe you can achieve what you want with a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) (using Newtonsoft Json). I will try and put together a code sample later.

That said, from what you have provided with your example, it looks like you are unnecessarily duplicating the data, which is hardly ever the best option.